# datepicker valid() function to check if the date is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this `datepicker` which is defined as `date-picker` class.
I want to check if the date is valid, I mean when the user modifies the date by keyboard, for example if enters day more than 31 or month more than 12 it should give an error.
I have written this `isValidDate` function but it does not work fine. I read somewhere that there is a `valid()` function for datepickers.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/qndnvff2/22/)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date-picker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });

  $(".date-picker").each(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="imageInputWrapper"></div>');
  });

  $('input:button').click(function(e) {
    $("#fDate").removeClass("red");

    var fromDate = $("#fDate").val();

    if (!isValidDate(fromDate)) {
      $("#fDate").addClass("red");
    }

    if (errors) e.preventDefault();
  });

  function isValidDate(date) {
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[2];
    var m = matches[2];
    var y = matches[3];

    if (y > 2100 || y < 1900) return false; // accept only recent & not too far years

    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d && composedDate.getMonth() == m && composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
  }
});
```

```css
.imageInputWrapper {
  width: 172px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
}
.red {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="fDate" class="date-picker" type="text" name="fromDate" style="width: 130px; height: 41px; background-color: white; border: none; outline: none; margin-left:5px" />
  <img src="http://s9.postimg.org/nl2mcq2rv/calendar.png" id="fromDateImgId">
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="submit">
  </table>
</form>
```

if you insert 44 in the day section it won't give any error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.parse()` for your validate function.

Example

```
function isValidDate(str) {
  return !isNaN(Date.parse(str));
}
```

Comment: the problem is not to check if it's a number or not, I want it to don't go further than a limit, days and months

Comment: `Date.parse()` will check your date string is valid or not, it's not only for checking numeric.

`Date.parse("44/04/2016") // -> NaN`

`Date.parse("01/04/2016") // -> 1451840400000`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Just a little bit tweaks.

```
function isValidDate(date) {
    var matches = /^(\d+)[-\/](\d+)[-\/](\d+)$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[1];
    var m = matches[2];
    var y = matches[3];
    if (y > 2100 || y < 1900) return false; 
    var composedDate = new Date(y+'/'+m+'/'+d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d && composedDate.getMonth()+1 == m && composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
  }
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ppw1k3yu/1/